# Output in Json format using dataweave

Tags: json, dataweave

I'm trying to convert the field-value mapping from CSV to Json format,below code is my dataweave code for mapping the fields from CSV and converting it into Json format:

```
%dw 1.0    
%output application/json    
---    
{

"volume":
[       
    payload groupBy $.StartDate map ((val,cal) ->
    {
        StartDate:val.StartDate[0],

        rows :
        [
            {
                AccountID : val.AccountID,
                ProductID : val.ProductID,
                Value : val.Value
            }
        ]
    }
    )
]    
}
```

Iam getting output as below :-

```
{

"volume": [
[
  {
    "StartDate": "8/1/2016",
    "AccountID": [
      "16482965",
      "16482966"
    ],
    "ProductID": [
      "12235398476-AR02",
      "12235398477-AR03"
    ],
    "Value": [
      "1720",
      "1722"
    ]
  },
  .
  .
  .
```

But i want my output to look like below :

```
  {

"volume": [
[
  {
    "StartDate": "8/1/2016",
    "AccountID":"16482965","ProductID":"12235398476-AR02","Value":"1720",
    "AccountID":"16482966","ProductID":"12235398477-AR03","Value": "1722"
   },
     .
     .
     .
```

Can anybody please here?

Comment: What you are showing as the desired JSON is not legal (or, at least, inconsistent). You have two instances of `AccountID`, `ProductID` and `Value`. I guess you meant to have one field for `StartDate` and an array of structures, each structure like one of the records (containing AccountID, ProductID and Value).

Comment: Yes @FDavidov - i want all the three fields AccountId,ProductId and value as an array of structures which is group by startdate.

Comment: I'll add the needed structure as an answer (impossible to do it here).

Comment: Sure @FDavidov,Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your answer to my question, here is the JSON structure you need to construct:

```
{
    "volume": [
                {
                    "StartDate": "8/1/2016",
                    "Entries": [
                                {"AccountID":"16482965","ProductID":"12235398476-AR02","Value":"1720"},
                                {"AccountID":"16482966","ProductID":"12235398477-AR03","Value":"1722"}
                               ]
                },
                ...
              ]
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Note the addition of the `"Entries"` element to the structure. It will allow you to run through the array by using references like:

```
...volume[n].Entries[j].AccountID
```

Hope this makes things clearer for you.

**UPDATE**:
I missed a closing `]`. Added now.

Comment: Hi @FDavidov,i have pasted the updated code,but iam getting the same structure again.Could you please check if anything is getting missed out!!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the language you are using to generate the JSON, and hence I can only guess (and most probably waste your time). my instincts tell me that the problem is with the `groupBy` at the beginning. Try removing/changing it. If that doesn't work... I can't help you beyond this point. And still, I would appreciate if you consider up-voting my answer since it did help you (identifying the wrong structure of the JSON).

Comment: No Problem @FDavidov,it helped me a bit and i voted for you .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i have used the below code,can you please confirm

```
     %dw 1.0
     %output application/json
     ---
     {
        "Transaction":"111",
        "type":"b002",
        "volume":
        [       
            payload groupBy $.StartDate map ((val,cal) ->
            {
                StartDate:val.StartDate[0],

                "Entries" :
                [
                    {
                        AccountID : val.AccountID,
                        ProductID : val.ProductID,
                        Value : val.Value
                    }
                ]
            }
            )
        ]
     }

And iam still getting the out put as :

            {
        "Transaction": "111",
        "type": "b002",
        "volume": [
          [
            {
              "StartDate": "8/1/2016",
              "Entries": [
                {
                  "AccountID": [
                    "16482965",
                    "16482966"
                  ],
                  "ProductID": [
                    "12235398476-AR02",
                    "12235398477-AR03"
                  ],
                  "Value": [
                    "1720",
                    "1722"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "StartDate": "7/31/2016",
              "Entries": [
                {
                  "AccountID": [
                    "16482964"
                  ],
                  "ProductID": [
                    "12235398475-AR01"
                  ],
                  "Value": [
                    "1720"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }   

          ]
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Now, your JSON is _legal_ but not what you need. You can use [this](http://jsonlint.com/) site to test the structure of the generated JSON. If there an error, it will show it to you. You still have extra `[` (e.g. after `"AccountID":`).